# Activating swipe tool in ERDAS imagine?

Tags: erdas-imagine

I am having a problem trying to enable (activate) the swipe tool in ERDAS imagine.

I used to use it but due to some reason the tool is deactivated.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you saw the following file, but since you did not provide any screen shot or further explanation, the pdf file on [how to use the ERDAS IMAGINE Swipe tool](http://community.hexagongeospatial.com/hmrkh95973/attachments/hmrkh95973/eTErdasImagine/7/1/Using%20the%20ERDAS%20IMAGINE%20Swipe%20Tool%20Script.pdf) may help you to figure out how to activate the swipe tool

Answer (score 1):

Just put both images on same 2D View
[image]